# How to make GDB recognize bi-endian code?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, endianness, icc

When trying to debug code that was compiled with Intel Bi-Endian compiler, I am having trouble viewing data.
This seems like my data was marked as big-endian.

The data I am trying to view is with `__be_x`, where `x` is an `int`.

Trying to print `x` when its value is one, I get this value, probably because this value is being interpeted as little endian instead of big:

```
(gdb) p __be_x
$4 = 16777216
(gdb) x /4b
0xf850aa0 <__be_x>:    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x01
```

So the value, interpreted as big-endian, is 1.

I think GDB has some kind of patch for this, but I can't seem to find it.
Do you know how to make GDB recognize the data?

Comment: You do not have a question in your post.  Are you looking to understand 16777216 (0x01000000)?  Are you looking for a GDB patch to present an alternative debug output?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a feature for this -- I think it would require DWARF extensions if you can use both big- and little-endian types in the same program -- but you might try "set endian".

You might also like the "apropos" command, which searches gdb's help text.  You can find the above command quite easily with "apropos endian".