# Why do variables and functions get prefixed with "__be_" when compiled with ICC bi-endian compiler?

Tags: c, gdb, endianness

I have compiled my C code using ICC bi-endian compiler.

And I am using `GDB 8.1.3`, for debugging.

When I run the GDB with my image as input file, and give a function name to put a breakpoint, it doesn't accept. It throws a message like -

```
Function "myFunction" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
```

However, if I try to put a breakpoint by pre-fixing the function name with `__be_` then it accepts -

```
(gdb) b __be_myFunction
Breakpoint 2 at 0x7777777b72347e: file ../abc/efg/src/source_file.c, line 123.
```

I am not able to understand what is the significance of `__be_` here? Why GDB is not able to understand the function name as is?

Note: With older version of `GDB - 7.2.2`, I can place the breakpoint with the function names as is; and don't have to prefix it with `__be_`

Comment: Are you sure the operative difference is between versions of GDB, as opposed to between versions of ICC, between operating platforms, or similar?

Comment: What do you mean by operative difference?
I&#39;m using the same compiled image as input to both GDB 7.2.2 and GDB 8.1.3

Comment: By "operative difference" I mean the one(s) that actually causes the behavioral difference to manifest.  That you are feeding an identical image to both GDBs partially answers that, but I'm still looking for other differences that might factor in.  In particular, that you're using a bi-endian compiler suggests that you may be aiming to support multiple platforms with the same binaries, so does the difference in GDB come with a difference in platform?

Comment: Related: [GDB with bi-endian code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19152836/2402272)

Comment: Did you build GDB 8.1.3 or is it provided to you?  Ditto for GDB 7.2.2.  Was GDB 8.1.3 configured to recognize the behaviour of the ICC bi-endian compiler?  What configuration was used to build each version?

Comment: @JohnBollinger — I've edited that question into better shape, and (for some reason I don't understand) SO now rejects the original 'GDB with bi-endian code' question title.  I've renamed it 'How to make GDB recognize bi-endian code?'.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I referred to that stack overflow question before, but that don't have a clear answer.
And we dont support multiple platforms with the same binary, we create different binaries for different platforms. (sorry, I might be understanding incorrectly, since you have a predicate to say it). 
I quite didn't understand when you say - "does the difference in GDB come with a difference in platform". The difference in GDB is the versions that I am using. And I am using the GDB on a x86_64 machine to debug.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have not built neither of the GDBs that I am using. Both we provided to me as a tool for debugging. From your question - " What configuration was used to build each version?", I feel that a GDB should be compiled with some configuration such that it recognizes particular style of compiled code (which in our case is a code compiled by bi-endian compiler). Have I got that right?

Comment: Your versions of GDB were compiled to recognize some set of compilers, and it appears that the ICC bi-endian compiler (what does 'bi-endian', as opposed — presumably — to 'big-endian' mean?) does things that GDB does not expect. If one version recognizes the bi-endian rules and the other doesn't, something happened in between. Probably, either the new version no longer recognizes the bi-endian changes at all, or it wasn't configured to recognize them. Some compilers add a prefix underscore to symbol names; GDB is configured to recognize that, I believe. The bi-endian prefix may be similar.